# From subquery giving error in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am having this query :

```
SELECT T.custno,T.custlastname,AVG(T.OrderAmount) , T.OrderCount
FROM(
      SELECT  A.custno,A.custlastname,count(b.ordno) as OrderCount,    sum(c.qty*d.prodprice) AS  OrderAmount
  FROM customer A 
      JOIN ordertbl B ON A.custno=b.custno
      JOIN ordline C ON b.ordno=c.ordno
      JOIN  product D ON c.prodno=d.prodno
  WHERE A.custstate='CO'
  GROUP BY A.custno,A.custlastname, b.ordno) AS T
GROUP BY T.custno,T.custlastname;
```

I get this error :

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

When i execute inner subquery explicitly, it runs fine. Please let me know the reason.

One can try at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b48d/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess You are missing one column in `group by` clause in outer query. Try the below query

```
SELECT T.custno,T.custlastname,AVG(T.OrderAmount) , T.OrderCount
       FROM (SELECT  A.custno, 
                    A.custlastname,
                    count(b.ordno) as OrderCount,
                    sum(c.qty*d.prodprice) AS  OrderAmount
             FROM customer A 
             JOIN ordertbl B ON A.custno=b.custno
             JOIN ordline C ON b.ordno=c.ordno
             JOIN  product D ON c.prodno=d.prodno
             WHERE A.custstate='CO'
             GROUP BY A.custno,A.custlastname, b.ordno) T
       GROUP BY T.custno,T.custlastname,T.OrderCount;
```

Comment: No, still same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT T.custno,T.custlastname,avg(T.OrderAmount) , T.OrderCount
       FROM (SELECT  A.custno, 
                    A.custlastname,
                    count(b.ordno) as OrderCount,
                    sum(c.qty*d.prodprice) AS OrderAmount
             FROM customer A 
             JOIN ordertbl b ON A.custno=b.custno
             JOIN ordline c ON b.ordno=c.ordno
             JOIN  product d ON c.prodno=d.prodno
             WHERE A.custstate='CO'
             GROUP BY A.custno,A.custlastname,b.ordno,OrderAmount,
             OrderCount) AS T)
       GROUP BY T.custno,T.custlastname,T.OrderAmount,T.OrderCount;
```